# OO simple question... importing same library from different classes

Tags: oop

If I build several classes and I import the same library for each class, am I going to make my project heavy ?

Or is exactly the same as importing it only once ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the linker (or it's equivalent) will ensure you have only one copy.

There are some subtleties with things such as Java Application Servers where you may want to "isolate" classes (typically applications) and so pay the cost of having duplicate copies of some common libraries.

Generally speaking just design/code naturally and the right thing will happen.